# Consulta com vários SELECT's MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT prefixo FROM getVeiculosLinha AS V JOIN getLinhas AS L ON V.cod_linha = L.cod_linha JOIN tab_garagens AS G ON V.prefixo = G.onibus_prefixo

SELECT c.local FROM status AS s JOIN cadastro_pontos AS c ON c.onibus_ponto = s.onibus_ponto JOIN tab_garagens AS t ON t.onibus_prefixo = c.local WHERE data > (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) GROUP BY s.onibus_ponto
```

As duas consultas são consultas distintas em que eu gostaria de gerar uma terceira consulta com os dados que **NÃO** estão duplicados; lembrando que ambas possuem uma coluna em comum (c.local e prefixo) que trazem a mesma informação porém de lugares diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

Como o MySQL não implementa FULL OUTER JOIN simule com UNION de LEFT JOIN e RIGHT JOIN e usando CTE para simplificar:

```
WITH
  cte1 AS (SELECT prefixo FROM getVeiculosLinha AS V JOIN getLinhas AS L ON V.cod_linha = L.cod_linha JOIN tab_garagens AS G ON V.prefixo = G.onibus_prefixo),
  cte2 AS (SELECT c.local FROM status AS s JOIN cadastro_pontos AS c ON c.onibus_ponto = s.onibus_ponto JOIN tab_garagens AS t ON t.onibus_prefixo = c.local WHERE data > (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) GROUP BY s.onibus_ponto)
  
SELECT prefixo, local FROM cte1 LEFT JOIN cte2 ON (prefixo = local) WHERE local IS NULL
UNION
SELECT prefixo, local FROM cte1 RIGHT JOIN cte2 ON (prefixo = local) WHERE prefixo IS NULL;
```

Comment: Amigo, esta alteração está ocorrendo erro por parte do MySQL, na linha WITH. Acredito que o MySQL, pelo que pesquisei, não exista mais esse comando. Porém não sei como fazer uma coisa mais elaborada para que funcione como eu preciso.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions